# Generating additional OpenCV libraries for Java using cmake

Tags: java, opencv, cmake

I develop an Android application that uses face recognition. But the standard library does not contain the org.opencv.face package.

As I found out, it needs to be generated from OpenCV Contrib using cmake. I used the following command to do this.

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=<path to opencv_contrib> <opencv_source_directory>
```

But there is no Java code in the generated files.

The console displays the following output.

```
-- Java:
-- ant:                         NO.
-- JNI:                         C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-17/include C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-17/include/win32 C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-17/include
-- Java wrappers:               NO
-- Java tests:                  NO
```

I tried adding the following parameters to the command.

```
-D BUILD_opencv_java=ON
-D WITH_JAVA=ON
```

But nothing changes.